# F# templates for Windows Phone 8 app development

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Are there any F# templates for Windows Phone 8 development ? I know that the Windows Phone 7/7.1 had an F# template which can be downloaded from the Visual Studio Gallery . Is there any F# templates for Windows Phone 8 ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a F# portable library and then reference it from a C# Windows Phone project

Comment: is this still accurate?